# Импорт данных из таблицы excel в базу данных sqlite при помощи sql запросов

Tags: excel, запрос, sql

Есть таблица в sqlite:
Наименование Количество Цена
Есть такая же таблица в excele.
Вопрос, как из таблицы excel импортировать все данные в базу данных при помощи sql запроса.

Answer (score 2):

1. Сохранить файл как CSV
2. Использовать команду .import:
3. Элемент списка

   .separator ","

   .import excel_file.csv your_table

Подробнее:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Answer (score 1):

А еще можно в Excel написать функцию, которая будет создавать SQL запрос.
Типа

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO [table] (name, price, qty) VALUES ('", A1, "', ", B1, ", ", C1, ");")
```

Вставить это во все строки таблицы в экслеле. Потом результат copy-paste в PhpMyAdmin (или что Вы используете для управлением базы данных) и запустить.

Это не самый лучший вариант, конечно. Но иногда это быстрее остальных вариантов. Особенно, если у вас таблица о трех колонках всего лишь...